# Cython - type of custom python object

Tags: performance, numpy, types, cython

I'm trying to populate an array quickly in python. 
The code I use is:

```
`%%cython
# init array
cdef N = 1000000 # should return an int but bugged
cdef int[:,:] = np.empty((N,10))
# populate array
for i in xrange(N):
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print i
    annoy_index[i,:] = t.get_nns_by_item(i,n=10, search_k=10000, include_distances=False)`
```

annoy_index is a 2d  array of integers.  The t object is a custom object from a pypi package which has no obvious type, and it's method t.get_nns_by_items returns a list of integers. 
Any idea on how to make the code work? 
Thanks
The errors are as below:

```
-----------------------------
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef int N = 1000000
cdef int[:,:] annoy_index = np.empty((N,10))
                             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/node2-stage/chamberlinm/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_83a8ecb650ff8c24ca387e9de72c36e9.pyx:2:30: undeclared name not builtin: np

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef int[:,:] annoy_index = np.empty((N,10))
# kinda slow 
for i in xrange(N):
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print i
    annoy_index[i,:] = t.get_nns_by_item(i,n=10, search_k=10000, include_distances=False)
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/node2-stage/chamberlinm/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_83a8ecb650ff8c24ca387e9de72c36e9.pyx:7:24: undeclared name not builtin: t
In [10]:
```

Comment: The code lacks `import numpy as np`, `cimport numpy as np` and a definition for `t`. Now, for what to do with your method, as it is not cythonized the line `annoy_index[i,:]` cannot be compiled to plain C and will remain slow. It will have to do list/tuple unpacking and conversion to integers anyway.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Nothing here needs `cimport numpy` (but the rest of the comment is absolutely right)